# freesansbold messing up my game

Tags: python, pygame

so i used cx_freeze to convert my script to a exe file, i start the exe file and it goes to my into screen where you can press play or quit. when i press play the game crashes and i get this http://prntscr.com/8ngyqr

and i dont use freesansbold in the game it all im using the comicsansms font, so i deleted the fled with the exe in it and then i downloaded freesansbold and put it in my pygame folder i ran the code to make the game an exe again and the same thing happened. so then i went into the files of the exe game and put freesansbold in the pygame file there and it still didn't fix it, can anyone help me because i have no idea what to do.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As stated in the introductory materials, we expect you to read and follow the help documentation when interactive with the other denizens of this site. Please review and follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

The short answer is "no -- we can't help you". You haven't supplied code, messages, and output necessary to diagnose the problem. When you provide those, we can take a shot at it.

Comment: Why did you accept the given answer? What did you do to solve your problem?

Comment: to solve it i had to put the FreeSansBold.ttf in the game files after i made it a exe,  i had to open racegame/lib/pygame and put it in there and i had to change the name of the text file to freesandsbold.ttf (all lower case) because it was looking for a file with all lower case even tho i had it capitalized in the python game file. and i didnt even use the freesansbold text in my game but it still needed to be in the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer i can give for this limited information is to try using 'freesansbold' instead of any other font and make sure you never use 'none' as a font. DON'T forget to include the freesansbold font file and all other resorces such as sprites in the same folder the the compiled game .exe file. you can find the font at this location if you installed python in the default location,C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pygame\freesansbold

```
good luck :)
```